# How do I implement two controllers in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am trying to implement ApiController in my StudentController, but the thing is that I have to implement BaseController also.

When I do this, it doesn't work

```
public class StudentController : BaseController, ApiController
```

How can I do this?

Comment: if you are going with a different approach please share it as an answer so that it will be helpful for future visitors. :)

Comment: i dropped it, not mixing service provider with consumer now

Comment: I can't mark it answer as it is not the answer i was looking for, I have already given you vote up.

Answer (score 5):

Make your `BaseController` derived from `ApiController`.

```
public class BaseController: ApiController
{
...

public class StudentController : BaseController
{
...
```

If you want to use WebApi and MVC in the same application probably you can go with different namespaces.

```
namespace Applicationrootns.Controllers
{
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        ....
    }
}

namespace Applicationrootns.Controllers.Api
{
    public class StudentController : ApiController
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

Now with this you can access

`applicaitonbase/student/`  and `applicaitonbase/api/student`

Comment: I can not do this because I am using some methods and properties in BaseController which are available in Controller class only.

Comment: Are you using WebApi with some MVC features? if so take a look at this http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2012/06/28/using-razor-together-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx

Comment: Yes, I am using both of them

Comment: How does the above code fills my requirement, i mean where i asked for implementing both api and base controller in student controller, creating two namespaces doesn't help

Comment: Well that's up to you.. i don't suggest/believe in mixing up my service provider with my service consumer even though they belong to the same application.

Answer (score 1):

Make you base controller inherit from the ApiController first, and then inherit your base controller from your student controller.

```
public class BaseController : ApiController

public class StudentController : BaseController
```

Comment: I can not do this because I am using some methods and properties in BaseController which are available in Controller class only.

Comment: What are the specific items that you need from the Controller class that you would like to use in an ApiController class?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Multiple inheritance is not allowed in C#. the other answers give you possible workarounds but you can't derive from multiple base classes. C# only allows for a single inheritance chain.